# Wordpress get_tags() not working with Wp-graphql plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-graphql

I'm trying to get tag urls with pagination. This is the full code. I'm trying to extend the wp-grapphql function. This way i'll be able to get tag paginated tag urls. I have morethan 30k tags so. I was able to sucessfully get paginated categories,post,author urls but dont know why this `get_tags()` not working as its suppose to in wp-graphql.

```php
//Get all tag urls for sitemap
add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {
    register_graphql_field('RootQuery', 'getTagUrls', [
        'type' => ['list_of' => 'String'],
        'args' => [
            'pageNo' => [
                'type' => 'int',
            ],
            'perPage' => [
                'type' => 'int',
            ],
        ],
        'description' => __('This function returns tag urls, It takes pageNo and PerPage as optional args.'),
        'resolve' => function ($source, $args, $context, $info) {
            $tagUrls = array();
            $paged = (isset($args['pageNo'])) ? ($args['pageNo']) : 1;
            $perPage = (isset($args['perPage'])) ? ($args['perPage']) : 10;
            $offset = ($paged - 1) * $perPage;
            $number = $perPage + $offset;
            $tags = get_tags(array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'number' => $number,
                'offset' => $offset,
            ));
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $fullUrl = esc_url(get_category_link($tag->term_id));
                $url = str_replace(home_url(), '', $fullUrl);
                array_push($tagUrls, $url);
            }
            return array_merge($tagUrls);
        },
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Why `$number = $perPage + $offset;`? You want the _same_  number of results _per_ page, do you not?

Comment: yes same number of results. in page two it should return next 10 urls not 20.

Comment: Well then you need to keep the `10` for `number` _constant_, not _increase_ it. The `offset` is what you need to increase - from 0, to 10, to 20, …

Comment: I also tried that and that does not work. at least this way when set the ```$paged``` to two it returns 20 result.

Comment: Even if i try to add a manual number the offset is not taking any effect as per i can understand.

Comment: Did you _verify_ what `get_tags` actually returned - or are you perhaps drawing faulty conclusions, because something else in your later processing of this data might simply be wrong somehow?

Comment: I'm getting the out put but not paginated, for example if i pass page one i'm getting 10 urls, but if i pass 2 its returning 20 urls not skipping first 10.

Comment: I have a almost identical code thats using ```get_categories()``` function and works as expected.

Comment: _“I'm getting the out put ”_ - are you specifically talking about what `get_tags` returned now, Yes or No?

Comment: No. I'm using the code in ```wp-graphql```, Its possible that there is conflict with ```wp-graphql```. Is there any other function that returns paginated tags.? I only need the tag url.

Comment: So why “No” then? _Sensible_ debugging includes that you figure out _from what point on_ things start going wrong.

Comment: I think the guy was right above.  $number needs to be constant.  $offset is the only number that goes up. ie (LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20, LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30, etc...)  perhaps there is an issue w/ your db query and it's not the code if changing the offset doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register your own type to get the tag urls and a pagination.

In the query `tags(first: 3)` sets the number of items per page. In this case 3.

```
query get_links_to_tags {
  tags(first: 3) {
    nodes {
      uri
      link
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
    }
  }
}
```

In the response, `endCursor` will be the last item.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "tags": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "uri": "/tag/apple/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/apple/"
        },
        {
          "uri": "/tag/atari/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/atari/"
        },
        {
          "uri": "/tag/sinclair/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/sinclair/"
        }
      ],
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI1MQ==",
        "hasNextPage": true,
        "hasPreviousPage": false,
        "startCursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjE3Ng=="
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, it's `YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI1MQ==`. This a base64-encoded string, you can decode it on [Base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/), you will see that it says `arrayconnection:251`.

When making the next query, use the value of that cursor as `after`.

```
query get_links_to_tags {
  tags(first: 3, after: "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI1MQ==") {
    nodes {
      uri
      link
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the next three items back.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "tags": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "uri": "/tag/tandy/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/tandy/"
        },
        {
          "uri": "/tag/sun-microsystems/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/sun-microsystems/"
        },
        {
          "uri": "/tag/xerox/",
          "link": "https://test.local/tag/xerox/"
        }
      ],
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI1NA==",
        "hasNextPage": true,
        "hasPreviousPage": true,
        "startCursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI1Mg=="
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, you have the `hasNextPage` and `hasPreviousPage` available for you to decide if you will put a previous-next button for the pagination.

Comment: This will not work in my case, I'm trying to create sitemaps for the tags and I have 30k+ tags on my site creating a dynamic sitemap in this approach will not work.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the setup? Is it a headless installation, or is there any other reason why you would like to fetch the sitemap through open graph? Maybe you are trying to solve a problem in a non optimal way?

Comment: I'm using wp-graphql for most of the parts but there are some situation that wp-graphql does not work, for example i need to create sitemap for mt site, As i said i have 30k+ tags and it will grow so even if i put 1000 urls in a page i need to create 30 sitemap only for tags. Here is the issues with wp-graphql we can only featch 100 items at a time but this can be ignored. Next problem is how can i know how many site map page should i have on the fly and then each of those page should show there respective links. I'm using nextjs SSR for the sitemaps.

Comment: May be if i was creating the sitemaps at build time it could be done using wp-graphql but my site have thousands of posts + everyday multiple posts are being posted so I'm using Nextjs SSR. I ended up extending the wodpress rest api, creating own api endpoint for this. BTW my code is working there, There is some kind of conflict with this tags function with wp-graphql.